# i want to update timestamp with respect to order_NUM. Help me with Update query on mysql. i have more than 5000 records with different timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```
#Order_num# ##Timestamp##
============================
1.1-126sdgf627  10-Sep-17 12:05:00.923 PM
2.1-12ad1f205f2 10-Sep-17 12:11:27.000 PM
3.1-12aiof38    10-Sep-17 11:58:11.574 AM
4.1-126fsdfog66 10-Sep-17 12:02:31.921 PM
5.1-12dakf56    10-Sep-17 12:13:44.000 PM
6.1-12fdsfo50   10-Sep-17 11:47:26.091 AM
```

ordernumber will be different for each records and timestamp also

Comment: Are you really expecting us to help you with such poor question demonstration?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET Timestamp ="whatever" WHERE Timestamp LIKE "%10-Sep-17%"
```

Comment: timestamp  field is null value